# A collaborative drawing app for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, collaboration, drawing

I have an Android and I'd like to draw together with someone who has iOS and who is on the other side of the globe. i.e. I want us to have a blank page where we could both draw freely in color, working on the same drawing.

The closest I found is "Whiteboard: Collaborative Draw" but after installing it I discovered that you can only collaborate over WiFi, so that doesn't solve my problem because my friend is in another country.

**Can anyone recommend a different app?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Google Drawings. I have great high school memories doodling with friends in class on PC. Its live-synced, names are color-coded, and all edits (revisions) are stored and undoable. You get to take advantage of Google's phenomenal servers, so everything loads rather quickly in my experience.

Docs on mobile may be just for text editing - I did a little research and found there is no Google Drawings app. For this to work without PCs, you need to open Google Drive in your browser and force desktop site (in chrome tap three dot menu and check "desktop site" box). Then, if you can get a handle of the unwieldy(small) UI everything should run smoothly. I believe this will work cross platform as both OS's support HTML5. This may be your best choice.

I'm looking for a social drawing app myself, so if you find anything good, let me know! I'm particularly interested in the concept of an infinite canvas that is live updating and publicly shared. Malmal early access on the play store is pretty cool but lacks the polish that time or a larger development team would offer.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively new app for creating basic drawings (flow diagrams and the like) in the browser is [Excalidraw](https://excalidraw.com/).
On [Github](https://github.com/excalidraw) :    Excalidraw whiteboard – easily sketch diagrams with a hand-drawn feel.
It has a "live edit" feature.

Discussion on [Hacker-News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=23525648#23527981) from 06/2020, mentioning a few alternatives.